# Print Server Failover

Tags: windows-server-2016

My company has a primary print server which is used heavily, and a secondary print server which isn't being used at all. They are Windows Server 2016 VMs hosted on a Hyper-V server. Is there a way to have the print queues failover to the secondary print server in the even of catastrophic failure of the primary? I've looked into failover techniques and it all seems as if the only failover is if the V-Host fails. They can be migrated automatically to a second V-Host.

Does what I'm asking make sense? Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: AFAIK, Microsoft removed the ability to cluster print servers, so you're probably looking at needing to use a third party solution.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft changed their print server clustering solution in Server 2012.  Their intended method now is by using Hyper-V clustering to keep a secondary server monitoring the primary, and failing to the secondary in the case that the primary is detected to fail.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj556311(v=ws.11)